# Predicting a Time Series data with LSTM in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to prepare a model that will predict the first two numbers from a given array of numbers. So, the input dataset is like this -

`[1 2 3 5]
 [4 8 5 9]
 [10 2 3 15]`

Output will be - 

`[1 2]
[4 8]
[10 2]`

So, the architectures of RNN are like below, (Taken from [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/))

[image]
Then, the basic architecture of I'm trying to achieve should be something close to this -

[image]

So, it should be a Many-To-Many network. (Resembles the fourth image)

Question - **So, how can I create this type of model with Keras?**

**My Findings -**

I tried something like this -

```
n_samples = 10000
input = np.random.randint(5,10, (n_samples,5))
output = input[...,0:2]
rinp = input.reshape(n_samples,1,5)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1,5)))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(rinp, output, epochs=1000, batch_size=500, verbose=1)
```

But as you can see, this is not even close. This is like an MLP. It does not utilize any time steps. Because, the input shape is - `(n_samples,1,5)`. So, there is only one time step.

So, my implementation is wrong.

I've seen some examples of One-to-One, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many examples from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/).

In Many-to-Many example, the author used the following code snippet.

```
length = 5
seq = array([i/float(length) for i in range(length)])
X = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
y = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
# define LSTM configuration
n_neurons = length
n_batch = 1
n_epoch = 1000
# create LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())
# train LSTM
model.fit(X, y, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=2)
# evaluate
result = model.predict(X, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=0)
for value in result[0,:,0]:
    print('%.1f' % value)
```

As you can see from the `X` and `y` values, the described model is like the one below -
[image]

Which is not the one I'm trying to achieve.

Any example regarding the architecture I'm trying to implement would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a Sequence-to-Sequence (seq2seq) model based on the drawing. There is a very nice [tutorial online](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) to get you started. Instead of predicting sentences, you can just predict fixed length tokens of length 2. This architecture and variants are often used for machine translation. Based on your data, I'm guessing you are trying to experiment with the problem of long-term dependencies in recurrent networks; otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use seq2seq for any practical purposes.

Comment: So, this type of model can't be done with one sequence?

Comment: It can be done, you can share the weights between encoder decoders by using the same LSTM layer etc. But seldom is this done for these tasks as the encoder decoder are concerned with different objectives.

Comment: Can you share an implementation, please? It would be super helpful.